# What is the value of $x$ in this logarithmic inequality?

Tags: logarithms

Please help me with this inequality :

$$\log_2 (x^2-2x) - 3 >0 $$

Answer (score 4):

The logarithm in base 2 is a monotonically increasing function so you have that:
$$\log_2 x > 3 \Leftrightarrow x > 2^3$$
In your case the argument of the logarithm is slightly more difficult but getting rid of the logarithm works in precisely the same way.

You'll end up with a quadratic inequality; can you take it from there?

---

If you have trouble with understanding why you can get rid of the log in that way, here are two other ways of looking at it:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\log_2 x > \color{blue}{3} \Leftrightarrow \log_2 x > \color{blue}{\log_2 8} \Leftrightarrow x > 8 & \quad \mbox{(rewrite $\color{blue}{3=\log_2 8}$)} \\
\log_2 x > 3 \Leftrightarrow 2^{\log_2 x} > 2^3 \Leftrightarrow x > 8 & \quad \mbox{(take both sides as the exponent of base $2$)}
\end{array}$$